# 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: `selector` option must be specified when initializing tooltip on the window.document object

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display a partial view within a tooltip in my index view. I would like the tooltip to appear when someone mouses over the software title. My javascript code is located at the bottom of my `_Layout` page.

Upon mouse over of a software title, the  tag title loads inside the tooltip, however, it never loads my partial.

This is really two questions in one:

1. Why am I getting the error stated in the title of this question?
2. Why will my partial not load within the tooltip?

Thanks!

Also, this is different than my other question as I have an error that arises within the javascript. I am not sure if my bundles and layout references are in the correct order.

Bundle Config:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/jquery.ui-{version}.js"));

        //Create bundel for jQueryUI  
        //css  
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/cssjqryUi").Include(
               "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/moment.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/PagedList.css"));



    }

}
```

_Layout Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - GHSP Software License Manager</title>

@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

@*<script src="~/Scripts/SoftwareDetails.js"></script>*@

</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("My Software", "UserSoftware", "SoftwareLicense")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("My Contacts", "UserContact", "ContactInformation")</li>
            </ul>
            <p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Hello, @ViewBag.FullName!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                @Html.Partial("_Footer")
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        var url = '@Url.RouteUrl(new{ action="SoftwareDetails", controller="SoftwareLicense"})';
        $(document).tooltip({
            items: "td.myToolTips",
            content: function (callback) {
                $.get(url + "?id=" + $(this).data("id"))
                    .done(function (r) {
                        callback(r);
                    });
            }
        });

    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Index View:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Software Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.SoftNameSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("License Type", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LicenseType, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("End Date", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.EndDateSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="myToolTips" id="@item.SoftwareID" title="Loading..">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SoftwareName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LicenseType)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.SoftwareID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.SoftwareID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.SoftwareID })
            </td>
        </tr>
        //count++;
    }
</table>
```

SoftwareDetails Action:

```
public ActionResult SoftwareDetails(int id)
{
    SoftwareLicense temp = db.SoftwareLicenses.Find(id);
    return Content("Tooltip for "+id);
}
```

SoftwareDetails Partial View:

```
@model WBLA.Models.SoftwareLicense

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SoftwareName)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SoftwareName)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SoftwareKey)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SoftwareKey)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentName)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DepartmentName)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LicenseFilePath)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LicenseFilePath)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LicenseType)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LicenseType)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.StartDate)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EndDate)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NotifyTime)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NotifyTime)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConsumerEmail)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ConsumerEmail)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EntryEmail)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EntryEmail)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

NOTE: When I navigate to the URL stated inside my javascript code at the bottom of the _layout page and provide an id in the URL, my partial loads fine. So I don't believe it is an error with my partial view.

Comment: The code should work fine. [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F8xi7l)  is a working dot net fiddle i created for your last (similar) question. I suggest you try the same code in a new-minimal project and share it so that we can take a look.

Comment: This is different than my other question as I have an error that arises within the javascript. I am not sure if my bundles and layout references are in the correct order.

Comment: All right. I reopened the question.

Comment: @Shyju Thank you, I appreciate it greatly! Also, I don't have time to make a new-minimal project to use as a test case as I have a deadline.